# How to collect data using php from an HTML form?

Tags: php, html

Suppose there is a HTML file that has a form in it , which contains some data , which have been taken input from the user using textarea and checkbox . How do I send this data across to a PHP file ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php, http://w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 2):

All form variables will be in $_GET or $_POST array in php (depending on which method you use to submit the form.

The textarea or checkbox need to be named like this:

```
<!-- HTML form -->

<form method="post" action="collect.php">
Comments: <textarea name="comments" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea> <br/>
Tick to select <input type="checkbox" name="checker"/> 
</form>



// collect.php    
$comments=""; if(isset($_POST["comments"])) { $comments = $_POST["comments"]; }
$checker=""; if(isset($_POST["checker"])) { $comments = $_POST["checker"]; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can post this data by submitting form and then on the php file you can use `$_POST['fieldname'];` for using value what you have on HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

The values from the form will be available in either, the $_GET and $_POST arrays, depending on the method used in the form.

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute of a form defines the php script (or other script) the form data gets send to. You will be able to get the data using `$_GET` and $_`POST`. In the following example the text inputs will get submitted to form_action.php

```
<form action="form_action.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```