# How to write a PHP code in HTML that allows POST?

Tags: php

I am a bit of a newbie to PHP thus need a bit of an explanation to this:

I want to post to a `http://url/?` using Java/Python or such.

And a PHP function to read that post and write it into a text file or into the HTML.

How do I do that?

Comment: Almost exactly 2 years ago you asked almost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426337/how-to-collect-data-using-php-from-an-html-form :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `$_POST`.

At a high level based on your requirements, this script would suffice to write it to a file named `filename.txt`, assuming your POST key was `body`:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $_POST['body']);
```

To "write it into the HTML", you should take care of escaping etc. Again, assuming your POST key is `body`, this would suffice:

```
<?php
echo htmlentities($_POST['body']);
```

Note that you should never ever trust user input directly to be output back into HTML, always escape it appropriately otherwise you're leaving yourself vulnerable to XSS/CSRF/whatever-else attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward.

You read out the POST data with the global array `$_POST`

so in your HTML add this:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['name_of_field'];
?>
```

it will echo the contents of the field `name_of_field`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, echo this in your html:

```
<?php echo $_POST['post_key'] ?>
```

To write to file you can combine [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with `$_POST['post_key']`