# Jquery not collecting info from an html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to use jquery to run a php file. The php sends some info to a database.

The php itself works. I can remove the js code and everything is sent to the database. It is obvious from looking at my db what is happening. The content in the forms isn't being collected. Some things make it into the database, but not the info from the form.

Here is my code, what could be the problem?

```
// submit without refresh
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {

        // Stop the form actually posting
        e.preventDefault();

        // Send the request
        $.post('submit.php', {}, function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            // Here we handle the response from the script
            // We are just going to alert the result for now
            alert(d);
        });
    });
});
```

My form does the have `id="form"` Why isn't the js collecting the form info?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting data from form?

Comment: You are not posting any values to the server

Comment: You pass an emtpy object as data to the `POST` request. You still need to serialize the form's data and pass it.

Comment: may be possible duplicate of this post..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426337/how-to-collect-data-using-php-from-an-html-form

Comment: @codebreaker, this isn't a duplicate. I mean I haven't posted this myself before. m90 How do I serialize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot post your form this way. $.post will have no idea about your form's elements unless you tell it what to send. To make above code works, you have to pass form's data to to $.post, for example:

```
$.post('submit.php',
    data: { <your form data here> },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass field values to your php script:

```
$.post('submit.php', {data: $(this).serialize()}, function(d) {
       console.log(d);
       // Here we handle the response from the script
       // We are just going to alert the result for now
       alert(d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the form data first. Serialize is used to get the form datas.

```
$(function() {
 $('#form').submit(function(e) {
    var data = $(this).serialize(); // get the form datas
    // Stop the form actually posting
    e.preventDefault();

    // Send the request
    $.post('submit.php', data, function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        // Here we handle the response from the script
        // We are just going to alert the result for now
        alert(d);
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Best way for send data is ajax method like:

```
var nameVar = $("#name").val();
var loc = $("#location").val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: nameVar, location: loc
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: So how would I make name get info from a field? Could I make it like `name: $('#name').val(),`? Why is this method best, could you comment a bit more on that please? By doing it liek that there is no preventdefault fall back though for when javascript is disabled.

Comment: yes you can or before calling ajax you can store all field values in different variable and replace like name:nameVar

Comment: Could you explain why you feel this method is best please?

Comment: i update my answer now you can apply this method, and how can you accept that answer that is right not a wrong answer but not fully perfect because mostly used json method to send or recieve data and that is always done by ajax call method with post/get, that is perfect method or you need to call xml like this check here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp